# Ubuntu Studio 22.04.1 LTS Terminal commands not changing hostname

Tags: command-line, hostname, konsole

When I set up my new install I typed in my username and didn't change the suggested hostname so it's currently 'user-hostname' so when I type in Terminal it shows as "user@user-hostname" and I'd like it to be just 'hostname' so "user@hostname"

I can't find a setting in the GUI and I've tried two different Terminal commands

sudo hostnamectl set-hostname

and

sudo hostname

I don't know why it's not working...

Thanks in advance!

Update: I must have missed it after my last reboot but it appears to have worked, Thanks for the assistance!

Comment: Have you rebooted after running `hostnamectl`?  If so, can you share what name you used?  There are some restrictions on the hostname.

Comment: I haven't rebooted, I'll try that and get back to you. The hostname is 'workhorse', I'm not changing the hostname, just wanted to remove my username and hyphen from in front of it.

Comment: I misunderstood.  That is set in your `.bashrc`.  Look for `PS1`.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I've rebooted it and it maintains the original hostname. I'll check out .bashrc and PS1 (sounds like my childhood lol)

Comment: It appears that rebooting did indeed resolve the issue, I can't see a way to upvote your comment or mark my question as solved. I feel like such a noob haha.

Answer (score 0):

on my server,i do this:

`vim ~/.bashrc +59`

- \u: username
- \h: user-hostname

[image: change the PS1]

after the change,ensure file effective:

`source ~/.bashrc`

and, it worked

- before :

[image: user@user-hostname]

- after:

[image: only user-hostname]